# Json criado incompleto

Tags: java, web-service, spring, jackson

Pessoal seguinte estava com um problema de loop no meu projeto ao criar o Json a aplicação entrava em loop. Consegui resolver o problema do loop com a anotacao @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference. Porem esta sendo criado um Json Incompleto segue:

```js
[{"clienteId":3,"clienteNome":"Teste","clienteRua":"Nestor Barbosa","clienteNumero":890,"clienteComplemento":null,"clienteGarrafaos":[{"id":3,"cliente":3,"garrafao":{"garrafaoId":3,"garrafaoNome":"Cristal"},"quantidade":0}]},

{"clienteId":5,"clienteNome":"Natanael","clienteRua":"Nestor Barbosa","clienteNumero":890,"clienteComplemento":null,"clienteGarrafaos":[{"id":6,"cliente":5,"garrafao":3,"quantidade":3},{"id":5,"cliente":5,"garrafao":{"garrafaoId":5,"garrafaoNome":"Pet"},"quantidade":3}]}]
```

Se olharem no array do segundo objeto no primeiro elemento iram ver o seguinte :

> clienteGarrafaos":[{"id":6,"cliente":5,"garrafao":3,"quantidade":3}

Comparando com o primeiro objeto ou ate mesmo com o segundo elemento do array do segundo objeto ele veio completinho.

Como fazer para vir tudo completo? Vou deixar o link do github com o projeto no branch de nome [StackOverflow](https://github.com/natanaelAguiar/controleGarrafao/tree/StackOverflow).

---------------- Edit --------------------------

Fiz alguns testes aqui e percebi que se o primeiro Cliente possuir o garrafao no segundo Cliente ele nao traz o nome do garrafao somente o id dele, ou seja, os atributos garrafaoNome e garrafaoId nao sao criados no Json. Segue:

```js
[{"clienteId":3,"clienteNome":"Teste","clienteRua":"Nestor Barbosa","clienteNumero":890,"clienteComplemento":null,"clienteGarrafaos":[{"id":3,"garrafao":{"garrafaoId":3,"garrafaoNome":"Cristal"},"quantidade":0},{"id":7,"garrafao":{"garrafaoId":5,"garrafaoNome":"Pet"},"quantidade":3}]},

{"clienteId":5,"clienteNome":"Natanael","clienteRua":"Nestor Barbosa","clienteNumero":890,"clienteComplemento":null,"clienteGarrafaos":[{"id":6,"garrafao":3,"quantidade":3},{"id":5,"garrafao":5,"quantidade":3}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema fazendo uma classe ODT pra cada model e mappeando a entidade para a DTO. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez falte ajustar as anotações, o `@JsonManagedReference` indica que a propriedade deve ser serializada, enquando o `@JsonBackReference` serve para omitir a propriedade da serialização.
Olhando o seu código, na classe Cliente existe a anotação `@JSONManagedReference` para `List<ClienteGarrafao>`, mas na classe clienteGarrafao não foram adicionadas as anotações para guiar o Jackson na serialização.

Esse link do Baeldung explica sobre as anotações: [link](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion).

Você pode tentar modificar sua classe ClienteGarrafao:

```
public class ClienteGarrafao {
    @JsonBackReference
    private Cliente cliente;

    @JsonManagedReference
    private Garrafao garrafao;
}
```

Comment: Olha tentei fazer o lance da classe ClienteGarrafao mas nao funcionou ficou do mesmo jeito, mas mesmo assim valeu!